# Prysm : Issue while onboarding new Validators in Testnet

Tags: testnets, clients, validators, prysm, dev-chain

I am trying to setup Devnet in my machine and things are smooth so far. But when I am trying to onboard new validators, it is

Waiting for deposit to be observed by beacon node" prefix=validator pubKey=0xa3a32b0f8b4d status="UNKNOWN_STATUS"

I followed the steps, provided!.. Staked the necessary tokens and I could see the balance in teh deposit contract.

public_key:"Mypublic key in hexa"  status:{activation_epoch:18446744073709551615}  index:18446744073709551615]
time="2024-01-05 20:23:50" level=info msg="Waiting for deposit to be observed by beacon node" prefix=validator pubKey=0x88c141df77cd status="UNKNOWN_STATUS"

Here, the activation_epoch & index value is set as maximum value of unsigned integer.. I almost tried all possibilities to set this up to recognize the new validator in devnet. but facing the same message..

Could someone please provide direction.. what would be the issue?

Fork_id is same and I am using Gensis_fork_version from config.yml file -< in staking-deposit-cli